# About Coinbase regional restrictions

Tags: exchanges, coinbase.com

Bitcoin noob here. Tried to open an account in coinbase to buy bitcoins. But, coinbase site said that I could not buy bitcoin in my region. I am outside the continental US.

Is this restriction because of where I live, or is it because of where they think my bank account would be? If I have a bank in the USA, would coinbase let me get bitcoins?